# Would computer keyboard be an example of a one to one function?

Tags: probability, statistics

Would a computer keyboard be an example of a one to one function? For example, a user inputs A and the output would be A, which appears to be a one to one function to me. However, in the event that the user inputs crtl+alt+delete, which requires multiple inputs at the same time to achieve its designated output. Would that still be considered a one-to-one function?

Comment: I guess if you defined the domain and codomain carefully, it could be seen as one.

Comment: What about computer games, w,a,s,d works same as right,left,bottom,up arrows.. Take an example of Need For Speed Carbon racing game. However you can change the setting

Comment: @Saf_Swathi_Rosogolla. Ah, good insight with the computer games example. I hadn't thought of that scenario. Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure this is a probability or statistics question

Comment: @WedgeWood Some era I was too addicted to computer games, that's why I guessed it clicked.(Hum bhi kisi zamane peh gaming kah shewag hua kate the.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to carefully define the inputs and the outputs of the function.  It seems clear that you should treat keys combined with modifiers as separate inputs, so shift-a, ctrl-a, ctrl-shift-a, and plain a are all different.  It seems the output should be the code the keyboard sends to the computer.  How your program treats it is not part of the question, so if a game accepts wasd as arrow keys it still gets the codes for wasd from the keyboard.  The greatest challenge I see is the two sets of number keys.  I suspect that the number keys (when unmodified) in the row above the keyboard and the number keypad to the right of the keyboard produce the same codes to the computer.  This would prevent the function from being one-to-one as two inputs make the same output.  Also on the numeric keypad I have keys for +-*/ which are duplicated on the main keyboard.  I also have versions of the keys that are arrows, home, pg up, pg dn, end which are on the main keyboard.